# How to use the setParameterList() method in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a requirement to fetch selected rows from Oracle database based on `ids` supplied as an array, something like the `SELECT ... FROM table_name WHERE id IN()` query.

In my attempts to do so, I'm trying to use the [`org.hibernate.setParameterList(String name, Object[] values)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-) method in my DAO as follows.

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public final class ProductImageDAO implements ProductImageService {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Object[]> getFileName(String[] list) {
        return sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("SELECT prodImageId, prodImage FROM ProductImage WHERE prodImageId=:list")
                .setParameterList("list", list).list();
    }
}
```

The parameter of type `String[]` in the given method is supplied from the respective Spring controller class.

It causes the following exception to be thrown.

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near
>   line 1, column 78 [select prodImageId, prodImage from
>   model.ProductImage where prodImageId=:id0_, :id1_, :id2_, :id3_,
>   :id4_, :id5_]

What is the way to retrieve the selected rows based on list of `ids` using Hibernate?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
String queryString = "select acc from cgix.trust.domain.PtbnAccount as acc where acc.accountId IN (:accountdIds)";
Query query = session.createQuery (queryString);
query.setParameterList("accountIds", accountFilter);
```

Assuming `accountFilter` is a `List` object. Keep in mind that you should not pass empty lists since that would result in the following SQL (which won't work):  `... WHERE xyz IN () ...` (note the empty in-clause).

Comment: Yes my HQL syntax was wrong. Replacing `where prodImageId=:id` with `where prodImageId in(:id)` worked.

Comment: The last query should be `query.setParameterList("accountIds", accountFilter);`, no?

Comment: Fukuzawa is right , should be query.setParameterList("accountIds", accountFilter), please update answer

Answer (score 8):

The problem that most people make here is that they still want to use,

```
query.setParameter("accountIds", accountFilter);
```

instead of

```
query.setParameterList("accountIds", accountFilter);
```

use `setParameterList()` when dealing with lists

Comment: how to set String[] array as query  parameter

Comment: @priyadarshini you use Arrays.asList(array)...