# Passing multiple values. getting org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, persistence

I'm reading query from a text file and depend upon the filters from the UI, With the string buffer i'm appending the additional queries.[image: Passing multiple fields like this]. Passing multiple id's like above to get the data

I'm getting nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number.

I'm using q.setParameter which is Java persistance Query. So i don't have paramterList.Because of comma between the values i'm getting Invalid number. Can you please help me what i can do here to support multiple values and can get the data.

My code sample:

```
StringBuffer q = new StringBuffer();

 q.append(queryFromPropertiesFile);

if( model.getId()!=null && ! model.getId().isEmpty())
q.append(" and emp.id IN (:id)");

Query query = entity.createNativeQuery(q.toString());

query.setParameter("id", model.getId());
```

Comment: Please see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296234/how-to-use-the-setparameterlist-method-in-hibernate

Comment: Thanks, but i want to use Java.persistence.Query not org.hibernate.query.Query.     org.hibernate.query.Query has setParameterList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `List` object (i.e., split your string using `,` delimiter) and then pass that list of ids (`List` object) to the `setParameter` as shown below:

```
List<String> idsList = new ArrayList<>();
String[] ids = model.getId().split(",");
for(String id : ids) {
    idsList.add(id);
}

query.setParameterList("id", idsList);
```

Comment: Actually I want to use setParameter, Not setParameterList. Please advise

Comment: If i use setParameter i'm getting the same error. Nothing changed sir.

Comment: What happens when you use `setParameterList`? What is the error?

Comment: setParameterList is method we can use from org.hibernate.query.Query. But here i'm using javax.persistence.Query. I need to use javax.persistence.Query and it doesn't has setParameterList

Comment: Thank you sir, i made some changes and it started working. Thanks a lot